# PHP/MYSQL - Unexpected T_STRING in query?

Tags: php, mysql

http://pastebin.com/nDZVrA2n (Sorry, I suck at putting code here!)
The problem occurs at line 34 - Where I'm trying to insert the page ID and the clients IP, however I get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in path/TSL/vote.php on line 34
```

I really don't get why I'm getting this error as I'm doing everything correctly from my perspective.
I've checked the code and everything - but alas, nothing.
If anyone has a solution, I'd be grateful.
Thanks!

Comment: To paste source code here, just indent it four spaces in the editor of your choice.

Comment: I'm also going to beat you over the head for not using [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) because this code is yet another example of why you should **never** use `mysql_query`. You are wide open to SQL injection attacks here because you don't escape `$page` every time it's inserted directly into a query and you're pulling it straight from the `$_GET` parameters and only giving it a light dusting. You've at least made the effort to escape *some* of your values, but PDO will make it easy to be sure *all* of them are done.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. [`addslashes()`](http://php.net/addslashes) is not sufficient for escaping. Use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string). Or even better; use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo).

Comment: I second using PDO but using PDO does not automatically make things secure. You need to use prepared statements. You can use prepared statements with PDO, MDB2, or even raw mysqli driver. But my point is, it's prepared statements that make it more secure, not PDO itself.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not an artifact, you have a backtick at the start of line 31 that the parser would choke on.

```
`   echo "<div class='header'><center>You've already voted for this server!<br><a href='http://bobcraft-games.com/TSL/'>Return to our homepage</a></center></div>";
```

Also you should consider trying MySQLi and parametrized queries so you don't have to concat together a bunch of stuff to make a query.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks! They are so hard to see in Dreamweaver, so no wonder I missed that xD